# Picking 1 result out of many from database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Problem:
I'm filling asp.net report from sql server by applying multiple joins on different tables. It works but creates a problem where am picking PoliceStation name by help of cell no. Problem is that 1 cell no can be of many police stations, so it picks each Policestation name and disply that it in report. I just want 1 police station name which i require from PoliceStations table

Query:

```
SELECT [ID]
      ,LEFT(REPLACE(convert(varchar, CmsSMSDb.dbo.SendMessages.SendingDateTime, 113), ' ','/'), 11) + ' ' +
       RIGHT(REPLACE(convert(varchar, CmsSMSDb.dbo.SendMessages.SendingDateTime, 113), ' ','/'), 12)
      as SendingDateTime
      ,[ToMobileNo]
      ,[Message]
      ,Designations.Name as [ToDesignation]
      FROM [CmsSMSDb].[dbo].[SendMessages] 
      inner join 
      CPOCMS.dbo.Designations
      ON CPOCMS.dbo.Designations.MobileNo = CmsSMSDb.dbo.SendMessages.ToMobileNo
      where Convert(date,CmsSMSDb.dbo.SendMessages.SendingDateTime)>= @DateFrom 
      AND 
      Convert(date,CmsSMSDb.dbo.SendMessages.SendingDateTime)<= @DateTo


      Union All

      SELECT [ID]
      ,LEFT(REPLACE(convert(varchar, CmsSMSDb.dbo.SendMessages.SendingDateTime, 113), ' ','/'), 11) + ' ' +
       RIGHT(REPLACE(convert(varchar, CmsSMSDb.dbo.SendMessages.SendingDateTime, 113), ' ','/'), 12)
      as SendingDateTime
      ,[ToMobileNo]
      ,[Message]
      ,'SDpo'+' '+CPOCMS.dbo.PoliceStations.PsName as [ToDesignation]
      From [CmsSMSDb].[dbo].[SendMessages] 
      inner join CPOCMS.dbo.PoliceStations
      ON CPOCMS.dbo.PoliceStations.sDpo_ContactNo = SendMessages.ToMobileNo
      where Convert(date,CmsSMSDb.dbo.SendMessages.SendingDateTime)>= @DateFrom 
      AND 
      Convert(date,CmsSMSDb.dbo.SendMessages.SendingDateTime)<= @DateTo
      order by SendMessages.ID
```

DB structure:

[image]

Comment: Apart from contact number, is there other column you need to consider, if not, you can simply take the top 1. or if you need a random one, then probably a random selection logic you need to add.

Comment: no nothing else and i have tried a lot but couldn't find any way

Comment: Store your output in Temp table, and get the top 1 of it. Or simply add top 1 in your selects

Answer (score 0):

Just use TOP clause like this.

```
SELECT TOP 1 ColumnA,
       ...,
...
...
..
```